Deneb visual not showing on web browser
I am using Deneb and I am assuming it's this syntax error thats not allowing viewing:
`
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at t.originalFunctionApplier (js-wrapper.js:2:289236)
at HTMLBodyElement.appendChild (js-wrapper.js:2:32242)
at HTMLBodyElement.appendChild (js-wrapper.js:2:118727)
at eo (cvSandboxPack.cshtml?locale=en-    GB&pbiglobals=1&csp=ZGVmYXVsdC1zcmMgaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAucG93ZXJiaS5jb20gZGF0YTogYmxvYjogJ3Vuc2FmZS1pbmxpbmUnICd1bnNhZmUtZXZhbCcgOw%3D%3D&McasTsid=26324:29:400766)
at vb (cvSandboxPack.cshtml?locale=en-GB&pbiglobals=1&csp=ZGVmYXVsdC1zcmMgaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAucG93ZXJiaS5jb20gZGF0YTogYmxvYjogJ3Vuc2FmZS1pbmxpbmUnICd1bnNhZmUtZXZhbCcgOw%3D%3D&McasTsid=26324:29:963172)
at r.loadWithoutResourcePackage (cvSandboxPack.cshtml?locale=en-GB&pbiglobals=1&csp=ZGVmYXVsdC1zcmMgaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAucG93ZXJiaS5jb20gZGF0YTogYmxvYjogJ3Vuc2FmZS1pbmxpbmUnICd1bnNhZmUtZXZhbCcgOw%3D%3D&McasTsid=26324:29:970685)
at r.executeMessage (cvSandboxPack.cshtml?locale=en-GB&pbiglobals=1&csp=ZGVmYXVsdC1zcmMgaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAucG93ZXJiaS5jb20gZGF0YTogYmxvYjogJ3Vuc2FmZS1pbmxpbmUnICd1bnNhZmUtZXZhbCcgOw%3D%3D&McasTsid=26324:29:973756)
at r.onMessageReceived (cvSandboxPack.cshtml?locale=en-GB&pbiglobals=1&csp=ZGVmYXVsdC1zcmMgaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAucG93ZXJiaS5jb20gZGF0YTogYmxvYjogJ3Vuc2FmZS1pbmxpbmUnICd1bnNhZmUtZXZhbCcgOw%3D%3D&McasTsid=26324:29:972622)
at cvSandboxPack.cshtml?locale=en-GB&pbiglobals=1&csp=ZGVmYXVsdC1zcmMgaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAucG93ZXJiaS5jb20gZGF0YTogYmxvYjogJ3Vuc2FmZS1pbmxpbmUnICd1bnNhZmUtZXZhbCcgOw%3D%3D&McasTsid=26324:29:964884
at kB.invokeHandler (cvSandboxPack.cshtml?locale=en-GB&pbiglobals=1&csp=ZGVmYXVsdC1zcmMgaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAucG93ZXJiaS5jb20gZGF0YTogYmxvYjogJ3Vuc2FmZS1pbmxpbmUnICd1bnNhZmUtZXZhbCcgOw%3D%3D&McasTsid=26324:29:850036)`
`

I have shared this Power Bi report with a few people, and it appears that some are able to view this visual while others are not.
any help would be appreciated
Tried to reinstall edge and reset all settings.

You should probably raise a Deneb issue here along with the sample .pbix causing the issue and all other requested details. https://github.com/deneb-viz/deneb/issues
